# Dashed number cipher

Tags: cipher

> 74393-493-71335-34393-1-83457102-377-13-57111-40129-3447-1-00-420-50371335-1-93057104-377-13-207-0340-737

Disclaimer: This cipher is not mine, but it was interesting and I managed to solve it. Credit: User Star on Discord, 8:54 EST on 9/10/20.

Comment: If it's not yours, it's necessary to (at minimum) attribute it to the original author.

Comment: @Bass I added credit. How do I reopen the question?

Comment: It needs enough reopen votes (5 IIRC) from 3k+ rep users. I just gave mine, so others will see a note in their review queues.

Comment: I think we could use a few hints or some additional information, i.e. who is asking this or where we can start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plaintext (presumably):

> there are times when i question why im still doing what i do and sometimes i question why im not dead yet

Decipherment and presumed key:

> ```
> 012345789
> oineast r
> dl mh   g
>    wu y q
>
> there are times where i qeustion wyy im still uoing what
> 74393-493-71335-34393-1-83457102-377-13-57111-40129-3447-
>
> i do and somtimes i qeostiou wyy im not dead yet
> 1-00-420-50371335-1-93057104-377-13-207-0340-737
> ```

Cipher:

> A polyphonic substitution cipher where each letter is assigned a single digit. While deciphering, a single digit will stand for one of several letters, so even a decipherer who knows the key must still choose the most likely letter from several options. That is, the solution is ambiguous. The solution I found also assumes no fewer than four misspellings or enciphering errors, but I'm fairly confident it is correct.

Solve path:

> Began with recognizing the idiomorphic pattern for `THERE ARE` in the first two groups of digits, and assuming the single digit `1` stood for `I`, then solved as a (damaged) polyphonic substitution with lots of trial and error.

Comment: Rot13(Gur funcrf bs yrggref naq pbeerfcbaqvat ahzoref ner fbzrjung fvzvyne. r.t.: 3-R,J,Z, 5-F,A, 0-B,...)

Comment: I suppose I would have noticed that if I was using capital letters. But that doesn't make it much better. It's still polyphonic and still full of mistakes. `707-493-207-38937730-70-50173-7415`

Comment: Correct, I found the same text and confirmed with the user back then. @ACB That's exactly what I used to solve it quickly and probably what they intended, for codewarrior0 to get it without any shape observation is impressive. How long did it take?